# Any recommendations on how i make this thing blink?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

[image: Picture of head]

I'm trying to rig a character with this head. I tried to find a tutorial for this, but the only thing I could find is shape for shape keys, the only problem is that I don't know how to deform it to a closed position without it looking weird. I'm asking for either

1. a easy way to deform it to a closed position while also being versatile enough to create unique expressions

or

2. another method that works better and is easier than shape keys.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello, are these supposed to be the pupil of the eyes and the occular globe? Also, maybe show a storyboard on how you want your pupils to close?

Comment: That's the head, I know weird shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could set the 3d cursor to the center of the sphere and make it the transform pivot point. Which allowed me to just use rotation